# Find $\int x\times\sqrt{8-x^2} \,dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int x\times\sqrt{8-x^2} \,dx = \,?$$
I got to this:
$$\int\sqrt{8x^2-x^4} \,dx$$
or:
$$\int\frac{8x-x^3}{\sqrt{8+x^2}}\, dx$$

I don't know how to integrate neither. If possible, no $\sin$ \ $\cos$ \ etc.

Comment: Have you seen the method of substitution before, sometimes called $u$-substitution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution $u=8-x^2$, and you’ll get an easy integration.

Answer (score 1):

Or directly:

$$\int x\sqrt{8-x^2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{8-x^2}\,d(8-x^2)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}(8-x^2)^{3/2}+C$$